# plotting multiple lines in one line plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that hast 3 columns. I made it up from a bigger dataframe like this :

```
new_df = df[['client_name', 'time_window_end', 'tag_count']]
```

then I used groupby to find out the number of tags for each client in each day using this code :

```
new_df.groupby(['client_name' ,'time_window_end']) ['tag_count'].count()
```

I totally have 70 client names in a list an I want to loop through my list to plot a line
plot for each costumer name. in the x axis I want to have 'time_window_end' and in the y axis I want to have 'tag_count'.
I want 70 plot but the for loop that I have written does not do that. I would be happy if you could help me to fix it.

```
clients = new_df['client_name'].unique()
client_list = clients.tolist()


for client in client_list[:60]:
  temp = new_df.loc[new_df['client_name'] == client]
  x = temp.groupby(temp['time_window_end'].dt.floor('d'))['tag_count'].sum()
  df2 = x.to_frame()
  df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
  df2["time_window_end"]= pd.to_datetime(df2["time_window_end"])
  line_chart = df2.copy()
  plt.plot(line_chart.reset_index()["time_window_end"], x)
```

Comment: An [mcve] would help us understand what you're trying to achieve. And please specify what output you expect and what you get instead. As it stands the title appears to contradict the body text.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this right, it sounds like the seaborn package might have what you need. The plotting functions take the argument 'hue' which splits plots up into multiple lines, based on the data in a column

```
import seaborn as sn

new_df = new_df.groupby(['client_name' ,'time_window_end']) ['tag_count'].count().reset_index()

sn.relplot(
    data = new_df, 
    x = pd.to_datetime(new_df["time_window_end"]), 
    y = 'tag_count', 
    hue = 'client_name', 
    kind = 'line')
```

EDIT: to get multiple plots

```
import seaborn as sn

new_df["time_window_end"] = pd.to_datetime(new_df["time_window_end"])

g = sn.FacetGrid(
    data = new_df,
    row = 'client_name')

g.map(sn.lineplot, 'time_window_end', 'tag_count')
```

EDIT again: to get separate plot images

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for name in pd.unique(new_df.client_names):
   sn.lineplot(
      data = new_df.loc[new_df.client_names == name],
      x = 'time_window_end',
      y = 'tag_count',
      label = name)
   plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I do not want all 70 lines in one chart. I want a chart for every  client_name

Comment: @KIMIAGhassemzadeh The question led me to believe the former. I've edited the answer. This will produce 1 plot per 'client_name'.

Comment: thank you so much for help , it worked the way that I needed, I really do appreciate it